# How to get the inspect element of auto complete box when we entering userids in web applications

Tags: jquery, html

When I am trying to enter a user id, the drop down box is showing with list of user ids which were logged in previously. What I want is I need to hide that drop down. To hide that drop down I tried with                     `autocomplete="false"` for my input tag it is not work out. So I am trying to hide that drop down using `jquery`.

if I know id or class of that drop down box so can any help me how to get inspect element of that drop down

I had image but I need 10 reputation to add image 
[image: you will see list of user ids while logging]

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share some code and markup? It would be hard for anyone to determine what is going on here.

Comment: Hello Jay,   In the above image I need to get the inspect element of drop down box  when I click on inspect element the drop down will gone so I am not able to see the inspect element of drop down.

Comment: Do you want to know the class used for that drop down?

Comment: I'm sorry @NareshReddyKallamadi that does not clear things up. Please add your code and markup to the question.

Comment: Inspect element will depend on the browser you are using?

Comment: Hello Jay, your exactly right I want to know class or id of that dynamically generated drop down by browser

Comment: I think that the correct way is `autocomplete="off"`...give it a try

Comment: Hello Robert, No I need to know class or id of that drop down,

Comment: @NareshReddyKallamadi and i'm telling you that the correct way is `autocomplete="off"`, not `autocomplete="false"`

Comment: hello robert I tried that also but its not work out for me  and following is my code       <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" id="<portlet:namespace />email" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Try this: `<input type="email" readonly class="form-control" id="<portlet:namespace />email" autocomplete="off"  onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>`

Comment: No robert it is not work out for me  still its showing that drop down.

Comment: Include the tag `novalidate` in the form...like `<form novalidate>`

Comment: Hello Robert, the  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="<portlet:namespace />email" autocomplete="off" />  When I tried without <form></form> its working  but when we place between <form> tags its not working

Answer (score 0):

when drop down is visible press `Ctrl+shift+c`. it will open the developer panel and once the elements start to highlight click on the drop down.

note: this might only work on html drop downs only. some browsers keep history of text inputs and those suggestions will not be inspected by this method. and this is only for google chrome and mozilla firefox, firefox with firebug add-on only.

Comment: hello Janaka, Thanks for your answering   so how can I get the inspect of history type drop downs

Comment: Hello janaka, the  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="<portlet:namespace />email" autocomplete="off" />  When I tried without <form></form> its working  but when we place between <form> tags its not working

Answer (score 0):

in the google chrome . Press F12 key. Then a window opens.[image]

select/click search icon at the top-left and click on the html element you want to inspect.

Comment: Hello Hitman, Thanks for answered   when I click on F12 the drop down will go into hide, by default it is showing by browser so I am unable to inspect that drop down

Comment: first press F12. Then when click on the drop down.It will show the html element inside console. Expand the html element.you can options inside the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an element such as `<div>` or `<span>` or anything else that you can hide with css or inspect it with developer tools, it's a part of `<input type="email">` element.

By default, `<input type="email">` has `autocomplete:"on"` that cause the email suggestions appear. You can simply hide it by adding attribute `autocomplete:"off"` to `<input type="email">`.

To see it in action, you can check this [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_email).

1. Submit a valid email, and click submit.
2. Type again email you've submitted before, you'll able to see an email suggestion.
3. Now, add attribute `autocomplete:"off"` to `<input type="email">`, click result button.
4. Type again email you've submitted before, now there's no drop down email suggestion appear.

Comment: Hello Agus, the <input type="email" class="form-control" id="<portlet:namespace />email" autocomplete="off" /> When I tried without <form></form> its working but when we place between <form> tags its not working

Comment: Have you checked the demo? In the demo I linked above, it work within or without `<form>` tag.